# Workflow progress depending on uploading documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, task-list

I'm quite new to Sharepoint and am learning on the way. I've read a lot about workflows and tasks but I can not seem to make it work right just yet.

Basically I want to keep track of a purchase system in a task list:

- The first document is a request. Once it is approved (in endless meetings) I upload it to SharePoint and the progress on my task rises to let's say, 10%.

- Next there's the budget proposition. I have uploaded the document and the progress goes to 25%.

- Then we do a bidding to find a contractor, and I upload that aproved document and progress goes up.
  - And so on.

All of this would be just one task

I know there's an aproval workflow, but it does not serve me right since the aproval happens in meetings. And still, I do not know how to put weight on the documents so it shows the progress on the task once it's uploaded.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @AndersEricsson, while I looked into DocSets it didn't worked like I hoped.

I found my answer, I just created a workflow in Sharepoint Designer to give "weight" to a document depending on a field the user apoints while uploading it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to achieve. The problem is probably that you want to have One instance of the workflow but at the same time be able to use multiple documents in one document library.

A document set would be the logical choice for a set of related documents. The set would include the document content types you describe (request, proposition, bidding etc).

The set would then have a running instance of a workflow that would contain the logic that you describe. The workflow would update a column "Progress" in the workflow task content type whenever a document within the set goes from minor to major version. Additionally, a column in the document set would be created and updated by the workflow so that the progress also could be shown and used in the document library.